# Ext JS - How to move component position to out of container with layout set

Tags: extjs

This example shows a button that when you click I am changing the XY to outside of its own container and also out of the container that has layout set. When clicked you will see the the button cut (if remove the layout config it works as expected):

[image]

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3puv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `align: 'stretch'` the inner container will have have space to show the relative button.

When you don't, the inner container will grow just to fit the containing items. So if you move the button, it will just be offset. As the overflow is hidden by default, you would not be able to see it.

You can set `overflow: visible` via css to the inner container:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3pvn

Comment: Thank you! Since I needed this for drag and drop only, while I am dragging out of hbox/vbox, I am changing the overflow style to visible for the container and for the innerCt of the layout and then after drop I put back the overflow for both element as was before. I hope this will not bring problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads up about overflow. Since I needed this for drag and drop only, while I am dragging out of hbox/vbox, I am changing the overflow style to visible for the container and for the innerCt of the layout and then after drop I put back the overflow for both element as was before. I hope this will not bring problems.